# EventCallback for dataLayer in google tag

Tags: google-tag-manager

I want to send some event using dataLayer.push.
Here is what i try:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    dataLayer = [];
    ga_data = JSON.parse('{{ga_data|safe}}');
    ga_data.eventCategory = 'Test Event Callback';
    ga_data.eventCallback = function () {
      var href = "{{ href }}";
      if((href.substring(0, 4) !== 'http') && (href.substring(0, 2) !== '//'))href = '//' + href;
      alert('sdf');
      window.location = href;
    }
    dataLayer.push(ga_data);

</script>

  <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','some id');</script>

  <noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=some-id" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>

</body>
</html>
```

So I want to fire callback after event has been sent.
First i get some ga_data object from json which already has eventAction, eventLabel and eventCategory set.

Then I try to append eventCallback to my ga_data and push it to dataLayer.

But it seems that eventCallback does not fire at all.

EDIT:
ga_data inside JSON.parse returns me valid json. If i try to console.log ga_data just before pushing it to dataLayer I get this:

```html
{eventCategory: "Test Event Callback", eventAction: "SINN", eventCallback: ƒ}
```

Comment: One problem might be that the string you are feeding to JSON.parse is not actually a JSON string.

Comment: @EikePierstorff, no it is correct, I edited my post

Comment: Do you have any tag actually firing on the event? My understanding it is that callback function will fire after all tags which fire on the event have executed. So if there are no Tags the callback might never be called?

Comment: @Matus, i check it with Google Tag Assistant, so i can see my tag. But in info of that I do not see callback attached. I see eventCategory and eventAction etc.